# Simple Calculator: Value in Function not defined but is listed in condition

Tags: javascript, function

After some extensive reading and help from the community I have started to create formulae in the form of calculators to practice my knowledge using my real world influences. I have created this calculator and added an additional condition to the equation but now the working calculator can't define a function which had worked previously.

The value is defined and given at the beginning of the function so I don't understand why it is not longer defined when adding the condition.

```js
var lsaForm = document.forms["lsacalc"],
  days = document.getElementById('days'),
  rlsa = document.getElementById("rlsa"),
  dayRateLsa = document.getElementById("rlsa"),
  rddlsa = document.getElementById("rddlsa"),
  tlsa = document.getElementById('tlsa');

function lsaupdateTotals() {
  var x = rlsa.value;
  var y = dayRateLsa.value;
  if (x == 1 || (y > 1 && y < 281)) {
rdlsa = 7.45;
  } else if (x == 2 || (y > 280 && y < 461)) {
rdlsa = 11.65;
  } else if (x == 3) {
rdlsa = 15.85;
  } else if (x == 4) {
rdlsa = 17.40;
  } else if (x == 5) {
rdlsa = 18.73;
  }
  let total = days.value * rdlsa;
  rddlsa.innerHTML = `Daily rate of LSA £${rdlsa}`;
  tlsa.innerHTML = `Total LSA Enitlement £${total}`;
}
```

Comment: 4th line: `dayRateLsa = document.getElementById("rlsa")` should't it read: `dayRateLsa = document.getElementById("**dayRateLsa**")` ?

Comment: aren't values strings?  use Number(xxx.value)...

Comment: `let total = days.value * rdlsa` => `let total = Number(days.value) * Number(rdlsa.value)` ???

Comment: I found that the issue came from not having the additional 'OR' conditions all through the calculator. This has resolved the problem, although the value of x is always returning as one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by applying the rest of the conditions throughout the function, the console returned an error but unspecified. Theoretically I think that the value of 'RDLSA' returned different with the additional conditions.

```js
function lsaupdateTotals() {
  var x = rlsa.value;
  var y = dayRateLsa.value;

  if (x = 1 || (y > 1 && y < 281)) {
    rdlsa = 7.45;
  } else if (x = 2 || (y > 280 && y < 461)) {
    rdlsa = 11.65;
  } else if (x = 3 || (y > 461 && y < 640)) {
    rdlsa = 15.85;
  } else if (x = 4 || (y > 641 && y < 821)) {
    rdlsa = 17.40;
  } else if (x = 5 || (y > 821 && y < 1001)) {
    rdlsa = 18.73;
  } else if (x = 6 || (y > 1001 && y < 1181)) {
    rdlsa = 20.07;
  } else if (x = 7 || (y > 1181 && y < 1360)) {
    rdlsa = 21.39;
  } else if (x = 8 || (y > 1361 && y < 1540)) {
    rdlsa = 23.40;
  } else if (x = 9 || (y > 1541 && y < 1720)) {
    rdlsa = 24.75;
  } else if (x = 10 || (y > 1721 && y < 1901)) {
    rdlsa = 26.09;
  } else if (x = 11 || (y > 1901 && y < 2081)) {
    rdlsa = 27.42;
  } else if (x = 12 || (y > 2081 && y < 2261)) {
    rdlsa = 28.77;
  } else if (x = 13 || (y > 2261 && y < 2241)) {
    rdlsa = 30.09;
  } else if (x = 14 || (y > 2241 && y < 2801)) {
    rdlsa = 31.43;
  } else if (x = 15 || (y > 2801 && y < 3160)) {
    rdlsa = 32.75;
  } else if (x = 16 || y < 3161) {
    rdlsa = 34.07;
  };

  let total = days.value * rdlsa;

  rddlsa.innerHTML = `Daily rate of LSA £${rdlsa}`;
  tlsa.innerHTML = `Total LSA Enitlement £${total}`;
}
```